# spark and impala in CDH Hadoop do not agree on the table schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, impala

Need some help as we are baffled.  Using Impala SQL, we did ALTER TABLE to add 3 columns to a parquet table.  The table is used by both Spark (v2) and Impala jobs.

After the columns were added, Impala correctly reports the new columns using `describe`, however, Spark does not report the freshly added columns when `spark.sql("describe tablename")` is executed.

We double checked Hive and it correctly reports the added columns.

We ran `refresh table tablename` in spark but it still doesn't see the new columns.  We believe we must be overlooking something simple.  What step did we miss?

**Update**: Impala sees the table with the columns but Spark does not acknowledge the new columns. Reading more about spark, apparently the spark engine reads the schema from the parquet file rather than from the hive meta store. The suggested work around did not work and the only recourse that could be found was to drop the table and rebuild it.

Comment: pls use `INVALIDATE METADATA <mytable>` - this is suitable for table structure change synchup. Refresh is used mostly for data refresh and not metadata refresh.

Comment: That is a command for Impala but not for spark. Impala sees the new columns but Spark does not

Comment: if your impala version is >3.3.0, it will auto refresh. else you need to run invalidate metadata in impala and then it should work in spark